# how to handle exception with non valid data type

Tags: c++

I want to handle the following error:
imagine I start writing a string instead of an int and the defined overloading operator is this:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Music& m)
{
    return is >> m.leng >> m.name;
}
```

so the first argument is an int and the second is a string but accidently I write a string
how can I handle this error?

Comment: You can set up [istream::exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I mean
I talk about simple input

Comment: If `is >>m.leng` could not read an `int` then `if(!is){}` allows you to do error handling. That can be done in the caller of your input stream operator.

Comment: @WernerHenze, how can I do if I want to restart the function in case of error, I mean I did like that but doesn't work:
`do
 {
  is >> m.leng >> m.name;
  try
  {
   if (!is)
    throw string("Error");
  }
  catch (string& e)
  {
   cout << e << endl;
  }
 } while (!is);
 return is;`

Comment: If `is >> m.leng` could not read a number, then it has not consumed any input. Why should that change when you try it a second time? It is still the same input, so the same failure would occur.

Comment: @WernerHenze yes, I got my error and I want to change it

Comment: @Backik "*I want to change it*" - change *what* exactly? Please be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I meant, if i forget that my first argument is an int so I enter a string, the error handler will occur then I know that I've made an error so I want to correct it

Comment: @RemyLebeau, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One you detect the error (either by checking the stream's state after `>>` returns, or by using `istream::exceptions()` to throw an exception on failure), then `clear()` the error, discard the bad input, prompt the user for good input, and then try to read again. Repeat if needed.

```cpp
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Music& m)
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
            if (is >> m.leng)
                break;
        }
        catch (std::ios_base::failure& e)
        {
        }
        is.clear();
        is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ');
        std::cout << "enter a valid integer" << std::endl;
    }
    while (true);

    is >> m.name;

    return is;
}
```

Though, I really do not recommend this approach. If your `>>` fails to read in a `Music`, let it fail. The caller should be the one to deal with the failure as needed, not your `>>`. Your original code was fine as-is.